# Spring boot auto reload stopped after upgrading from 2.1.13 to 2.2.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Following is the relevant part of my POM

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.13.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I have devtools installed as you can see. It works fine with version `2.1.13.RELEASE`. When I make a change in Java class and hit Build Project in Intellij IDEA, the server restarts with the new change as expected.

But when I upgrade the spring boot version to `2.2.0.RELEASE` or `2.2.5.RELEASE`, the auto restart stops working. When I make a change and build project, nothing happens. I check the docs, according to which adding devtools dependency should be sufficient.

Docs referred: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/pdf/spring-boot-reference.pdf (Page 37)

**Update 1**: I have created a demo application for anyone to try and see if it is working for them. [Here's](https://github.com/lokeshh/spring-demo-library) the repository. Try running it using `mvn spring-boot:run` and at run time edit `BookApi.java`, rebuild and it should trigger live restart.

**Update 2**: Here are the logs I get on starting the app: https://gist.github.com/lokeshh/d111c1429323ddf6e4a8d020526ceccb

**Update 3**: I tried STS 4 to test if the problem is with my IntelliJ or not. And I found out that same problem is there in STS 4. Auto reload is working for 2.1.13 upon save but not for 2.2.0.

**Update 4**: Deleted the complete `.m2` repository, still the same problem. Here are the logs with devtools trace enabled https://gist.github.com/lokeshh/d111c1429323ddf6e4a8d020526ceccb#file-output_with_trace-log

Comment: Works for me with windows 10 and intellj community version 2018.2.4 for both spring boot versions.

Comment: Hi Lokesh, I took your repo on my local, now which pom are you using so that I can test ?

Comment: It sounds like DevTools isn't active when you upgrade to Spring Boot 2.2.x. The log output from your application would show if that's the case. One possible cause  is a corrupted jar file. You could try deleting Maven's local cache and rebuilding your application.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I cleaned the maven cache by deleting whole springframework folder. The problem persists. These are my logs https://gist.github.com/lokeshh/d111c1429323ddf6e4a8d020526ceccb

Comment: That looks OK. Can you please enable `TRACE` level logging for `org.springframework.boot.devtools` and share the logs again? You can do so by adding `logging.level.org.springframework.boot.devtools=TRACE` to your `application.properties`. It's also worth upgrading to Spring Boot 2.2.6.

Comment: [These](https://gist.github.com/lokeshh/d111c1429323ddf6e4a8d020526ceccb#file-output_with_trace-log) are the logs with trace enabled for devtools @AndyWilkinson

Comment: Thanks. `file:/home/bluecoin/Desktop/spring_tutorial/library/target/classes/` is the location that is being monitored for changes. Please check that this is the location to which your IDE is writing the updated class files when you make a change. Also, as I recommended earlier, please upgrade to Spring Boot 2.2.6.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I updated to `2.2.6`. Also IDE is writing the updated classes as I created a new controller file while running the server and it appear in `/home/bluecoin/Desktop/spring_tutorial/library/target/classes/com/example/library/controllers` when building but the server still not reloading and no logs are there after the initial ones. Also I verified by using grep in the `.class` file to check if existing files are being modified or not and the changes are being written to `.class`, so look like IDE is writing classes as expected.

Comment: Sorry, I'm stumped then. At this point, I'd be reaching for the debugger and running the app with a breakpoint in `org.springframework.boot.devtools.filewatch.FileSystemWatcher.Watcher.scan()` to see what's happening.

Answer (score 5):

Well it worked for me as well just like other people who answered for you.

**But** I have solution for you here. It may happen sometime. Do the steps mentioned below.

As you have already added the ***dependency*** in `pom.xml`, so lets move to next step.

***Next***

Confirm setting in **intellij**. .

=> ***Build Project Automatically***

**File –> Setting –> Build, Execution, Deployment –> Compiler –>** `check this Build project automatically`

[image]

Then, Check ***Intellij Registry***

Press `SHIFT+CTRL+A` (Win/*nix) or `Command+SHIFT+A` (Mac) to open a pop-up windows, type `registry`

[image]

Find and enabled this option `compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running`

[image]

***Done***. Now, the hot swapping & static files auto reload should be enabled.

If the static files are not reloaded, press ***`CTRL+F9`*** to force a reload.

- ***/*       Post Comment devtools link added      */***

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-devtools-restart

Comment: I followed your steps, still its not working. So, one if clear that something is wrong with my Intellij but how do I fix it?

Comment: I have added additional link at the end of my answer. Follow. That will help you lot in details.

Comment: see the new link I have added. That is very detailed.

Comment: I just found out that problem is not with my IDE because I get the same problem in STS 4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212167/discussion-between-kunal-vohra-and-lokesh).

Answer (score 3):

For Both versions, Auto Restart is working for your code on my setup . Though I am using STS-4-4.6.0 release.

But one thing i noticed that it was giving failed to refresh live data warning, so I added below code in pom.xml and the warning was also removed

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Note: It was working for me with or without in STS, but you can still try this in Intellij , might be this is causing some issue, as the LiveReloadServer is the one actually used by devtools to autoload

This is printed in log when liveReloadServer is up:
LiveReload server is running on port 35729

Answer (score 3):

The code is working for both **2.1.13.RELEASE** and **2.2.0.RELEASE** on my macOS catalina with STS 4.

Note : From [Spring Documentation on spring-boot-devtools](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.8.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html)

[image]

Automatic restart varies from IDE to IDE.

*Marked in red are ones for Eclipse and Intellij.*

There is difference between reload and restart.

[image]

The auto-restart is happening.

Everytime, I'm running your application. I'm getting this warning.

[image]

How to resolve this :

1. By Adding dependency in pom.xml for spring-boot actuator for scraping live information

   `<dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>`

But still your application restarts.

Screenshot for application running with 2.1.13.RELEASE :

"abcd" as base string

[image]

I changed it to "abc" :

[image]

Restart status (for 2.1.13.RELEASE):

[image]

Restart status (for 2.2.0.RELEASE):

[image]

Comment: @Lokesh Is this answer helpful to you ?

Comment: I can't understand why isn't it working in Intellij IDEA. I can't switch to STS as I'm comfortable using Intellij IDEA.

Comment: @Lokesh I have already added screenshot on how to build project in Intellij.

Comment: I tried to see if STS 4 works for me and there too its the same problem. Auto reload does work with STS 4 upon I save file for spring boot version 2.1.13 and not for 2.2.0.

Comment: @Lokesh You same code is working already on my system wih STS 4. You can see the screenshot as well that I have added. I guess some other issue is there.

Comment: @Lokesh I have added screenshot for both 2.1.13 and 2.2.0 working screenshot as well.

Comment: @Lokesh I checked your logs. I don't think the code that you provide us was containing the db related things. Isn't it ? Because my logs and your logs are different.

Comment: @Lokesh Try by deleting .m2 folder from your side.

Comment: I deleted the complete .m2 folder, still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `File > Settings > Compiler > Check the box of Build project automatically`.
Hit Apply and Ok
[image]

Now go to `File > Settings > Advanced Settings > Check the box of Allow auto-make to start even if developed application is currently running`.
Hit Apply and Ok.

Now everything will work fine.
[image]

Comment: Official answer from JetBrain:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-274903/In-IntelliJ-20212-compilerautomakeallowwhenapprunning-disappear-Unable-to-enable-live-reload-under-Spring-boot